# How many files should be listed as open under lsof?

Tags: linux, centos, lsof

I am not an advanced Linux user. I have a VPS with 768MB of RAM running CentOS.

I executed the `lsof` command as root and I see that there is a list of 3000 files. Usually, how many files should be there?  My system is getting very slow, so is this list too long?

How do I know which files to keep and which to close?

I have seen that there are multiple copies of the same files with different PIDs. There are many log files in the list that I have not opened. Is this normal?

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        104287        492     103794          0          0          0
```

Comment: @DragonLord, why did you re-capitalize lsof? It's a command and it is typed without caps.

Comment: I didn't see your edit, sorry.  Corrected.

Comment: No problem, I thought maybe you meant something different than the command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running slow and you want to make your computer a little faster, you generall shouldn't be worried with the output of `lsof`. You should be looking at your processes and seeing (1) what they are using and (2) the current levels of your memory and CPU.

If you regularly find processes consuming 70%+ of memory, it might be time for an upgrade.

Comment: 1) How can i find how much total memory i am using 2) So u mean lsof has nothing to do with memory

Comment: You can use the command "top", which will display an up-to-date list of all processes and what they are using. On the top, you can see your total memory and used memory (in kilobytes). If not, I'm sure CentOS has a task-manager style  of GUI.

Comment: And lsof simply lists all the open files, it doesn't really let you know what they're doing and how much res sources they are using.

Comment: Find total memory with the `free -m` command.  Keep in mind that your total free RAM is the amount listed in "free" plus the amount directly under it on the next line where it says "-/+ buffers/cache".  I have 1595 open files on my 512MB RAM 1.2Ghz system and it isn't slow.  Open files take a few bytes of memory but don't in and of themselves consume a lot of CPU.

Comment: Thanks for that command @ultrasawblade, I forgot about it.

Comment: @ultrasawblade , i written the ouput of free -m in my questions. is that all right

Comment: @Donkey: You have tons of free memory, so that isn't an issue.

Comment: @Mirage you can check total ram with `free -m` or use some free monitoring solution, e.g. https://trafikito.com which would track output and give you a notification when you are running out of ram. Disclaimer, I work at Trafikito.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be worried about the number of open files. As the `lsof` man page tells, "open file" can be almost any readable file, stream or device, so the unfiltered listing can be long.

> An open file may be a regular file, a directory, a block special file, a character special file, an executing text reference, a library, a stream or a network file (Internet socket, NFS file or UNIX domain socket.) A specific file or all the files in a file system may be selected by path.

If no parameters are given to `lsof`, it lists all open files, including those opened by system daemons - such as the log files you mentioned not having opened. An open file reference consumes very few system resources, so that's no issue in itself.

I've just booted a live Ubuntu 11.04 from a USB stick and `lsof` shows over 4500 open files.